# QAbstractTableModel: cannot check data on creation

Tags: c++, qt, qabstracttablemodel

I've subclassed the QAbstractTableModel, and I've created a signal that must be emitted when a `QModelIndex` data of a specific column is changed.

in the `void data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const` I've written something like this:

```
Variant DerivedClass::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
  if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
  {
    switch (index.column())
    {
      // ....
      case NAME_COLUMN_INDEX :
      {
        return updateName(index);
      } break;
    }
  }
  return QVariant();
}
```

and this is `updateName`

```
QString DerivedClass::updateName(const QModelIndex &xIndex) const
{
  QString xName;
  if (false == xIndex.data().isNull() && true == xIndex.data().isValid())
  {
    xName = m_xDataVector.at(xIndex.row()).getName();
    if (xName != xIndex.data().toString())
    {
      emit nameChanged(m_xCellName, xName); // m_xCellName is specified otherwise
    }
  }
  return xName;
}
```

In this case, when I create the widget that uses this model, I have a memory exception in this row:

```
if (false == xIndex.data().isNull() && true == xIndex.data().isValid())
```

If I change my method by removing reference to data like this:

```
QString DerivedClass::updateName(const QModelIndex &xIndex) const
{
  QString xName;
  xName = m_xDataVector.at(xIndex.row()).getName();
  return xName;
}
```

I have the data updated correctly in my table, but signal is not emitted when name changes.

How can I check correctly the data that I must update in order to notify when they are changed?

EDIT:

From my callstack I've noticed that the crash is due to recursive calls. in `DerivedClass::data()` I call `DerivedClass::updateName()`, and in this `xIndex.data()`. xIndex is my instance itself, so I've a recursion with infinite deep.

I've found the problem, but I cannot find a way to retrieve data at specified row and column in order to perform my check.

Comment: Isn't `xIndex.data()` produce the recursive call of your `DerivedClass::data()` function?

Comment: Yes, I've just checked with my callstack. I didn't think so. So I need to know how to retrieve data at specified cell and column.

Comment: But why do you need data in `DerivedClass::updateName()` function? You do not use it at all, except checking for being valid. What if you simply check `if (xIndex.isValid())`? You even do not need any check, because `DerivedClass::updateName()` called for valid indexes only.

Comment: I did not know that the QModelIndex was referred to class itself. I've think that was a separate object so I needed to check for it. This was my mistake.

Comment: Btw, there is `QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged()` signal too.